# Using Backbone.js in an ES2015 module – imports are failing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use Backbone.js in an ES2015 module. At the top, I import parts of it using `import { View, Events } from 'backbone'`. Still, later in the code I have to refer to it as `Backbone.View` and `Backbone.Events` instead of just `View` and `Events`.

While investigating, I found out that Backbone [exports itself as global](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L18), so I believe that I actually use the global version instead of the imported properties. This is of course far from optimal and I would like to change this, but I am not sure how.

Since Backbone doesn't really make use of the `exports` keyword (although it's used in the UMD wrapper, but then is passed in as `Backbone`, which I don't quite understand), I guess I can't import parts of it without using something like RequireJS' `shim` feature.

Can I do anything about it or is Backbone.js just not suited to be used in ES6 modules?

Comment: I don't think you can make Backbone an ES6 module without writing your own adapter (`export const View = Backbone.View; …`)

Comment: You could just use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile your es6 code. This way you can use the Backbone distributed with npm.